# how to create (or run) .jar file from .scala files?

Tags: eclipse, scala, jar

There's an open source program called CIMCheck (http://wiki.cimtool.org/CIMCheck.html) that is supposed to be a command line utility which is run with command

```
    java -jar cimcheck.jar [option...] argument1 argument2
```

When I downloaded the source code, there was no .jar files at all, only a couple of .scala files and others.

So I have a following directory tree

```
   CIMCheck 
          -.classpath
          -.gitignore
          -.project
          -CIMCheck.launch
          -CIMCheck.xml
          -scaladoc.sh

          lib
              -scala-library.jar
          src
             au
               com
                  langdale
                           cimcheck
                                   -Checker.scala
                                   -CIMCheck.scala
                           util
                                   -CommandLine.scala
```

prefix "-" means it's a file; whereas, names without prefix are folders.

I've downloaded Scala, and tried to compile/run mentioned .scala files with scala compiler/interpreter but there are some mistakes at compiling/running a files.
i tried runing scaladoc.sh as a shell script in cygwin on windows, but no success.
I guess I need to run only CIMCheck.scala, as a .jar but don't know how
If you need the code from the *.scala files, let me know, and I'll repost.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have a `.project` and `.classpath` file in there indicates that this is probably an [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) project. Try opening it in Eclipse (you'll have to File / Import / Existing project into workspace).

Comment: it is an eclipse project.
when I run CIMCheck.scala (which is the only .scala file that has main) in eclipse, it just prints a text on console, within eclipse, where it says how to use it in command line i.e. `java -jar cimcheck.jar [option...] argument1 argument2` , but i have no idea how to start it from a command prompt or make a .jar file which I could execute from command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

1. In the Eclipse menu, select `File > Export > Runnable JAR file`, select the `CIMCheck` launch configuration, and check the "Save as ANT script" option.
2. Check if the output file includes `scala-library.jar`. If not, add it to the script created on the last step and rerun it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't access http://git.cimtool.org/ right now but I would guess that there would be a readme or so about buildihe project. I see on the CIMCheck website mention of using Eclipse, so perhaps there is an Eclipse project included and you are excepted to build CIMCheck via the IDE?